# NSWindowController designated initializer puzzle

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to make this code work:

```
class MyWindowController: NSWindowController
{
  let thing: Thing

  convenience init(thing: Thing)
  {
    self.thing = thing

    super.init(windowNibName: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "MyNib"))
  }
}
```

The problem, of course, is that a convenience initializer can't call `init` from a superclass. So how do I initialize my `thing` and still be able to call `init(windowNibName:)`, which is itself a convenience initializer? I'd rather not have to re-implement the nib loading myself, but how do I avoid it if I can only use designated initializers?

Comment: Your subclass will inherit its superclass's convenience initializers if it doesn't declare a designated initializer of its own.  Your problem is more that your initializer can't be a convenience initializer because your `thing` property needs to be initialized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the `NSWindowController` documentation:

> You can also implement an `NSWindowController` subclass to avoid requiring client code to get the corresponding nib's filename and pass it to `init(windowNibName:)` or `init(windowNibName:owner:)` when instantiating the window controller. The best way to do this is to override `windowNibName` to return the nib's filename and instantiate the window controller by passing `nil` to `init(window:)`. Using the init(window:) designated initializer simplifies compliance with Swift initializer requirements.

You can implement your class as:

```
class MyWindowController: NSWindowController
{
    let thing: Thing

    override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name? {
        return NSNib.Name(rawValue: "MyNib")
    }

    init(thing: Thing) {
        self.thing = thing

        super.init(window: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about `windowNibName`. Is there a more general solution for this problem? Or does it always require a workaround like this?

Comment: What is "this problem" exactly? Do you mean the need to call a designated initializer when using `super.init...` ? It all depends on the classes involved.

Comment: What if I ran into a similar situation with another class but the equivalent of `windowNibName` wasn't there? It seems like it's a workaround for not being able to call a convenience initializer from a subclass. I don't understand the purpose of that restriction.

Comment: Each case needs to be handled in whatever way makes sense for the class involved. See the [Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216) section of the Initialization chapter in the Swift book.